# Worker Role with Service Bus won't start

Tags: azure

from 2 days I am trying to start a wokring role with Service Bus support.
I have tried also to delete the cloud services and deploy again but the Worker Role remain always in this state:

Busy (Waiting for role to start... System startup tasks are running. [2014-05-30T07:21:49Z])

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot the code in your role OnStart method. Remove all of the code, see if that works, and add the code back in until it breaks. Another option is to add some real-time logging (using something like [Log4Stuff](http://log4stuff.com)) so that you can watch the code as it progresses.

The message specifically calls out startup tasks, so see if you have any startup tasks in your csdef file. If you do, you'll need to troubleshoot those separately.

It almost certainly is something in the packages you're deploying, so go through the process of adding/removing code until you can get a different result, or as I mentioned, beef up the logging so that it becomes easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The series at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx will walk through exactly how to troubleshoot role startup failures.  In particular, Scenario 3 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/06/troubleshooting-scenario-3-role-stuck-in-busy.aspx) should help troubleshoot roles that are stuck in Busy state.

Short answer: Look at the WaHostBootstrapper log to see where the startup process is stuck.